# MySQL 14 day reset query

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm building a basic system that selects 2 staff members at random to support the business for half of the day. I'm really struggling with the database and how I would actually go about completing this task as they've listed certain rules which are making it quite tricky.

Business Rules:

- An engineer can do at most one half-day shift in a day.
- An engineer cannot have half day shifts on consecutive days.
- Each engineer should have completed one whole day of support in any 2
  week period.

I'm a real beginner with this, but so far this is how I think of the problem:

Two Tables:

> EMPLOYEE:

```
employee_id (pk)
first_name
last_name
```

> SHIFTS:

```
shift_id (pk)
employee_id (fk)
shift_hours
```

> SAMPLE DATA:

```
 1. shift_id = 1, employee_id = 1, shift_hours = 4
 2. shift_id = 2, employee_id = 2, shift_hours = 6
```

---

```
 1. employee_id = 1, first_name = steve, second_name = jones
 2. employee_id = 2, first_name = rob, second_name = helen
```

---

My question is as follows: Based on the data above, what can I query to ensure that I am picking only users from the database that have only worked LESS than 8 hours in the past 14 days (How can I go about this 14 day issue, can there be some kind of "reset" 24 hours after somebody hits 8 the 8 hour mark, is that possible?)

Hopefully my question is clear, I do apologise as I am a bit of a beginner.

Thanks in advance

(This is different from my previous question, please see the bottom, I have merely just copied the explanation of the problem)

Comment: You need to include at least sample data and expected output in your question

Comment: Added sample data, is this what you are referring to? Apologies if not, I don't use stackoverflow too much!

Comment: I have reopened your question because you have added some data related to your problem but in future do consider to also include your attempt to achieve the solution no matter it is not correct but atleast show us that you have put some effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing i would not necessarily do `shift_hours` i would do like `started_at` and `ended_at` and make them datetime columns. This way you can do date math in your query to derive the amount of time worked, and you can select between specific dates.

With that as the premise maybe the tables look like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `shift` (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  started_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  ended_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  employee_id INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `shift_employee_id` (`employee_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY `shift_employee_id_fk_employee_id` (`employee_id`)
    REFERENCES `employee` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

So now we could query like:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, SUM(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, s.started_at, s.ended_at))) as shift_hours
FROM employee e, shift s
WHERE e.id = s.employee_id
AND s.started_at BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-15'
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING shift_hours < 8;
```

This would give us only employees who have logged less than 8 hours between the given dates we supply.

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/280d88/6
(note, i didnt want to generate enough data to use your 14 day rule, but you should get the idea).

The other rules are ones you will want to apply in the logic of your code when assigning shifts. Though you could probably do it in a stored procedure.

Comment: Wow this is an amazing help, thank you so much! Really made some things a bit clearer for me.

I'm trying to run the insert script you've added on the sqlfiddle page, but for some reason it doesn't seem to appreciate it like that, am I doing something wrong? I am using phpmyadmin and running it as a query, I did try it as an INSERT but it asked for the values like this

```INSERT INTO `shifts`(`shift_id`, `employee_id`, `started_at`, `ended_at`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4])```

Thought I'd ask with you before manually adding it line by line, thanks!

Comment: Sorry I've fixed it now, I was being a bit silly. Really do appreciate your help prodigitalson!

Comment: Sorry one more thing, may I ask, did you manually generate the data for my table? Or is there a program you used that can help me with things like that, cheers.

Comment: I manually did that, which is why i didnt use your actual range of 14 days... i didnt feel like generating that much data. Normally id just script something like that to load testing fixture.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks a lot, sorry that must've been a bit of a pain! Thanks for your time.